# RabbitMQ Queue Expires While in Use

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, easynetq

I have created RabbitMQ queues with `x-expires` policies using EasyNetQ [(`ISubscriptionConfiguration.WithExpires`)](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/a5222fef5fee45a6ddfa1ced6a202e2e9b603daa/Source/EasyNetQ/SubscriptionConfiguration.cs#L59). I am experiencing situations where queues that *have consumers* expire and get deleted, unexpectedly ending my subscription to the queue.

The [official RabbitMQ docs on Queue TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl) specify that

> Queues will expire after a period of time only when they are not used **(e.g. do not have consumers)**.

It also defines "unused" as meaning

> **the queue has no consumers**, the queue has not been recently redeclared (redeclaring renews the lease), and basic.get has not been invoked for a duration of at least the expiration period.

Based on this, I would expect that a queue would only expire if it has no consumers. Meaning that, even if a queue has not gotten a message for the duration of the expiration period, a consumer of the queue would prevent it from expiring.

Is my interpretation of the docs incorrect? Why would my queues expire if they have a consumer?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. How long is the expiration, are you sure there's not a network hickup?

Comment: My `x-expires` value is `28800000` (8 hours), so I suppose a network hiccup would be possible in such a timeframe. When I last experienced this, I double-checked whether the connection that spawned the consumers still existed, and it did.

I also have `auto-delete` enabled. Is there a chance that a queue created by EasyNetQ could get auto-deleted by a network hiccup?

Comment: Yes, auto-delete will immediately delete the queue when all consumers are disconnected, so it's basically an x-expires=0.

Comment: I have the same problem, I do not have autodelete enabled, just the WithExpires option, there is still a connection to the MQServer, they are on the same physical machine, so not a network issue.  But the queue is removed from the server after the expires period, even though my program is still listening for messages.

Answer (score 0):

Remove auto-delete from your policies or queue declarations.

Auto-delete will immediately delete the queue when all consumers are disconnected, so it's basically an x-expires=0 (immediately after disconnect).